# How to Stream Audio (Radio ) MvvmCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am having some difficulty stream online radio in Android Using MvvmCross. I found the plugin Xamarin MediaManager and tried to go that route.

Here's the code:

```
 public IMvxCommand ListenCommand => new MvxCommand(Play);
    private void Play()
    {
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("http://ic2.christiannetcast.com/wayg-fm");
    }
```

In my axml, there is a button bound to that command and pressing it outputs this in the console:

```
[MediaPlayer] Couldn't open http://ic2.christiannetcast.com/wayg-fm: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://ic2.christiannetcast.com/wayg-fm
```

I've tested it with several different links just to make sure that wasn't't the case. Also, I've made sure to have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in my AndroidManifest.xml

I've also tried using Android's MediaPlayer, but I get the exact same result.

Please let me know if there is something I am missing. I haven't found any solutions online regarding this issue. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am running this on an Android emulator, not a real phone. Don't know if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [MediaPlayer] Couldn't open xxx java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: xxx

[void setDataSource(String path)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#906):

> Sets the data source (file-path or http/rtsp URL) to use.
>
> @param path the path of the file, or the http/rtsp URL of the stream you want to play

[setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#906):

> Sets the data source as a content Uri.
>
> @param uri the Content URI of the data you want to play
>
> **which assumes URI to be of some form of ContentProvider**

## Solution:

Change your `MediaPlayer` `SetDataSource` method from:

```
mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
```

To:

```
mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(url);
```

---

I test it on my side and it works fine:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.Reset();
mediaPlayer.SetDataSource("https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3");
mediaPlayer.Prepare();
mediaPlayer.Start();
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on my emulator. I'll give it a shot on a real phone and let you know.

Comment: I'm running it on an LG Nexus 5

Comment: @Scout43, would you mind share a basic demo so that I can reproduce your issue on my side?

Comment: Ok, so the issue I found out is that the stream will play; however, It takes about 20 seconds to load. I found this out by just leaving the app alone, and eventually it starts to play. Is there anything I can do about this? Perhaps I can create a WebRequest and manually download/buffer the stream? Every where I look online people are saying that MediaPlayer is slow with loading.